# Error importing css in vue js single file component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to import 2 css files in style tag of my vue js single file component.

```
<style >
    @import '../assets/styles/jquery-ui.js.css';
    @import '../assets/styles/jquery-ui.css';
</style>
```

but the is throwing error saying:

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
>   9:28:42 AM
>
> error  in ./src/components/Attend.vue
>
> Syntax Error: Unclosed string
>
> @
>   ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-5d10c7ca","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/Attend.vue
>   4:14-308 13:3-17:5 14:22-316  @ ./src/components/Attend.vue  @
>   ./src/router/index.js  @ ./src/main.js  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on webpack, after compiling all the files inside your assets folder will be pack into `static` folder. Therefore when you import files/css/images in your component, your relative path is `'../static/styles/jquery-ui.js.css'`.

Therefore your code should be like this:

```
<style >
    @import "../static/styles/jquery-ui.js.css";
    @import "../static/styles/jquery-ui.css";
</style>
```

Comment: thanks can you also please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/q/53967042/3311276 .